# Trying to issue ERC 3475 tokens

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, error

I'm trying to issue ERC 3475 tokens from a relatively simple contract using Remix. The contract compiles and deploys when gas is optimized, but when I try to issue the tokens I get an error of "code=Invalid Argument". The problem is the Tuple that is supposed to entered. I'm not sure how to fix it. Reviewing the doc https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3475 , I've still have issues.

I believe here is where the issue is [IERC3475.Transaction(1,14,500)]. I'm trying to understand what do i put in there to issue the bond tokens.  Here is also a sample contract i'm using to try to issue tokens.

```
contract Token is ERC3475 {

    address public publisher;
    uint256 public lastAvailableClass;

    struct Data {
        uint256 onChainDate;
        string identificationNumber;
        string warrantNumber;
        string[] authorName;
        address[] authorChainAddress;
        string[] sponsorName;
        string domain;
        string subdomain; 
        string introduction;
        string[] keyWords;
        string license;
        string[] cover;
    }

    modifier onlyPublisher{
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        publisher = msg.sender;
        _classes[0]._values["nonceProprity"].stringValue = "{'0':'ownership'}";
        _classes[0]._values["category"].stringValue = "proprity";
        _classes[0]._values["subcategory"].stringValue = "object";
        _classes[0]._values["childCategory"].stringValue = "artifact";
        
        _classes[0]._values["warrantorName"].stringValue = "ShangHai";
        _classes[0]._values["warrantorType"].stringValue = "ShangHai";
        _classes[0]._values["warrantorJurisdiction"].stringValue = "ShangHai";
        _classes[0]._values["warrantorRegistrationAddress"].stringValue = "ShangHai";
        _classes[0]._values["warrantorURL"].stringValue = "ShangHai";
        _classes[0]._values["warrantorLogo"].stringValue = "ShangHai";
        _classes[0]._values["warrantorDocURL"].stringValue = "ShangHai";
        _classes[0]._values["warrantorIndustry"].stringValue = "ShangHai";
        _classes[0]._values["warrantorChainAddress"].stringValue = "ShangHai";
       }

    function _issueToken(
        address _to,
        IERC3475.Transaction memory _transaction
    ) internal {
        Nonce storage nonce = _classes[_transaction.classId]._nonces[_transaction.nonceId];

        //transfer balance
        nonce._balances[_to] += _transaction._amount;
        nonce._activeSupply += _transaction._amount;
    }
    function getPaper( uint256 classeId) public view  returns( Data memory result){
        result.onChainDate = _classes[classeId]._values["onChainDate"].uintValue;
        result.identificationNumber = _classes[classeId]._values["identificationNumber"].stringValue;
        result.warrantNumber = _classes[classeId]._values["warrantNumber"].stringValue;
        result.authorName =_classes[classeId]._values["authorName"].stringArrayValue;
        result.authorChainAddress =_classes[classeId]._values["authorChainAddress"].addressArrayValue;
        result.sponsorName= _classes[classeId]._values["sponsorName"].stringArrayValue;
        result.domain =_classes[classeId]._values["domain"].stringValue;
        result.subdomain = _classes[classeId]._values["subdomain"].stringValue;
        result.introduction= _classes[classeId]._values["introduction"].stringValue;
        result.keyWords= _classes[classeId]._values["keyWords"].stringArrayValue ;
        result.license= _classes[classeId]._values["license"].stringValue ;
        result.cover = _classes[classeId]._values["cover"].stringArrayValue;       
   }

    function publishProprity(
        uint256[] memory _amount,
        Data memory _inputValues
    ) public onlyPublisher {
        lastAvailableClass++;
        uint256 newClassId = lastAvailableClass;   
        _classes[newClassId]._values["identificationNumber"].stringValue = _inputValues.identificationNumber;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["warrantNumber"].stringValue = _inputValues.warrantNumber;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["authorName"].stringArrayValue = _inputValues.authorName;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["authorChainAddress"].addressArrayValue = _inputValues.authorChainAddress;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["sponsorName"].stringArrayValue = _inputValues.sponsorName;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["domain"].stringValue = _inputValues.domain;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["subdomain"].stringValue = _inputValues.subdomain;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["onChainDate"].uintValue = block.timestamp;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["introduction"].stringValue = _inputValues.introduction;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["keyWords"].stringArrayValue = _inputValues.keyWords;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["license"].stringValue = _inputValues.license;
        _classes[newClassId]._values["cover"].stringArrayValue = _inputValues.cover;

        _mintOwnershipTokens(newClassId, _amount, _inputValues);   
        emit classCreated(msg.sender, newClassId); 
    }

    function _mintOwnershipTokens(
        uint256 _classId,
        uint256[] memory _amounts,
        Data memory _inputValues
    ) private {
        require(_amounts.length == _inputValues.authorName.length, "Token: invalid length for _amount");


        // mint the ownership tokens to co-authors
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < _inputValues.authorChainAddress.length; i++) {
            Transaction memory _transaction;
            _transaction._amount = _amounts[i];
            _transaction.classId = _classId;
            _transaction.nonceId = 0;       

            _issueToken(_inputValues.authorChainAddress[i], _transaction);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need square brackets for the array and for the Transaction struct. See image.

[image]